# Android textview stackoverflow when using Hebrew

Tags: android

My app is retrieving data from a RESTful http source.
Sometimes, there will be Hewbrew text.
title קול המדיה, עמוד הבית
content הפיג'מות - עונה 6 פרק 12 עכשיו לצפייה ישירה! קישור: הצג את הדף

Everything is fine until it has to be used in a textview.
I'm using my own list adapter and the following happens when this text tries to get loaded:

```
I/dalvikvm( 2524): Stack overflow, expanding (0x41048200 to 0x41048000)
I/dalvikvm( 2524): Shrank stack (to 0x41048200, curFrame is 0x41049cd8)
D/AndroidRuntime( 2524): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2524): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2524): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime( 2524): java.lang.StackOverflowError
E/AndroidRuntime( 2524):        at android.text.Styled.drawText(Styled.java:290)
```

So, I tried to use a try/catch around the code, but I no help.  The catch doesn't catch this exception.

My code:

```
try{    
   holder.content.setText(currPage.GetContent())      
   holder.title.setText(currPage.GetTitle());      
} catch (StackOverflowError e){      
   e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

That doesn't work because that's not where the exception is actually happening.  It's when the text is being drawn onto the screen.  I don't know how to stop this from happening.
I really would rather just have a blank field if that is the easiest fix, but I don't know how to detect for Hebrew text is decent way.
Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Cheers,
Terry.

logcat output:

```
I/dalvikvm( 2411): Stack overflow, expanding (0x41048200 to 0x41048000)
I/dalvikvm( 2411): Shrank stack (to 0x41048200, curFrame is 0x41049cd8)
D/AndroidRuntime( 2411): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2411): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411): java.lang.StackOverflowError
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.text.Styled.drawText(Styled.java:290)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:1366)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:339)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:3921)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:5838)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1486)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1484)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:5841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1486)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:5841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1486)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1319)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:2820)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:5944)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2121)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1486)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1484)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:5841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1486)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1484)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1484)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1484)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1484)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:5841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1486)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1484)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:5841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1217)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1030)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1482)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2411):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

NOTE:  The original post and title said Arabic. It's been correct to say Hebrew.  Maybe it matters.

Comment: That's actually Hebrew in your example, not Arabic, FWIW (but the same basic issue, probably -- right-to-left text).

Comment: Oohh.  Thanks for the correction.  Maybe that'll help in my searches.  I updated the question to say Hebrew too.

Answer (score 0):

I have written Arabic text to a TextView many times without seeing a stack overflow exception, which is also a Right-to-Left (RTL) language.  Did you modify the `onDraw()` method or any other method that might be causing this error?

If you can't find the reason, this should return `true` if the given `inputText` contains Hebrew characters:

```
Pattern.matches("(\\p{InHebrew})+", inputText);
```

You might also want to disallow any non-Latin characters if other languages cause problems as well.  This site contains a list of all of the unicode scripts you can match against: 

[Regex Tutorial - Unicode Characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response.  I've made no changes to onDraw() or any other method.  I just setText() and that's it.