# android baseAdapter weird error

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

as mentioned in some other threads i'm a having trouble to setText inside a Textview from my BaseAdapter.

whenever i'm trying to set hebrew string inside it, i get a stackoverflow error.. when setting english string - works perfectly
i'm trying to find out where exectly the error is, so i've break apart each piece of my code and this is what i've found:
when my text view is nested inside a new view - the stackoverflow appears..

in this XML there is stackoverflow (only in hebrew string):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow>

        <include
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            layout="@layout/list_profile_picture_green"
            android:padding="4dp" />

        <TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        </TableLayout>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

this XML shows hebrew perfectly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow>

        <include
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            layout="@layout/list_profile_picture_green"
            android:padding="4dp" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />


    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

this is my stacktrace:

```
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483): java.lang.StackOverflowError
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:312)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:44)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at java.util.Formatter.outputCharSequence(Formatter.java:1114)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1086)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1062)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1031)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2183)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2157)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.text.Styled.drawDirectionalRun(Styled.java:266)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.text.Styled.drawText(Styled.java:362)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:1546)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:380)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4417)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6933)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1648)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3217)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3030)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-24 00:48:02.565: E/AndroidRuntime(20483):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.P
```

any idea why ???

Comment: In your "broken" XML, with Hebrew, what happens if your `textView1` object is within a `TableRow`? Additionally, what is the code you use to set the text in the `TextView`?

Comment: as i said, when it is inside a table row (or any other layout) i get a stackoverflow... i'm setting it simply by using setText("hebrew string")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error with the text itself. When using this exact code (sans the `include`), I have no errors with English, nor with Hebrew, with either XML layout.

The issue here is that you have too many nested layouts. I suspect this `TableLayout` is included in something else, which is from something else, etc...

You have to reduce the amount of nested layouts; I suspect the reason this is presenting itself as a `StackOverflow` error is because Hebrew reads right-to-left and also takes up more space to represent, so it's what's pushing the memory over the limit.

I believe you have the same issue listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954103/android-textview-stackoverflow-when-using-hebrew) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946368/stackoverflow-caused-by-nested-views).

Reduce the amount of nested layout items you have and this should go away. (As general practice, for example, a `TableLayout` within another `TableLayout` is bad practice.) [This](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) may help.

Comment: i've actually changed it all and i'm using Relative layout, it i was curious to see if anyone will be able to find out what the problem is..
nested table were in my head from HTML, but i guess you're right.. too many nested elements is no good for no one... :) thanks !